Lots of anonymous edits that just alter punctuation
The review queue for suggested edits has a lot of edits "by an anonymous user" that don't seem to make any substantive changes, but replace various punctuation characters by HTML entity versions of themselves.  Each one has "555-555-0199@example.com" as its comment.
Example:

It appears that the only change is to replace a ' character by &#39;.
Is this some sort of weird spam, or what?  I have been rejecting them as "vandalism".

A similar thing showed up on security.SE. They suggested it might be an automated vulnerability scanner.

Link???????????? of the review?

@Braiam: I already reviewed the edit so it's no longer in my queue. I don't know how to get a link for it anymore. Do you?

@NateEldredge https://i.sstatic.net/712Jn.png

@Braiam http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/19195

@bjb568: Thanks, I never noticed that was there.

@bjb568 I can't seem to link it, but if you click the markdown button, you can see what was actually changed.

Related: really strange post edit: maybe a spammer's test?. Another incident: https://security.stackexchange.com/posts/2264/revisions. The cause? Using Burpsite to spider the site which automatically submits forms.
